# FTP reverse proxying based on hostname/domain

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy

I just set up nginx as a http/https reverse proxy and it worked well.

After that, I realized that for some domains ftp services are available. I was able to install ftp.proxy and it also works well, although it just handles one single domain.

My question is: Is there any possibility to reverse proxy ftp services based on hostnames/domains like I do with nginx for http?

Comment: For a similar question/request, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814178/ubuntu-12-04-2-lts-subdomain-reverse-proxy-ftp-site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: There's `SuSE FTP-Proxy Suite`, which is a lightweight, easy to configure ftp-proxy for exactly the task you are looking for. It used to be easy to install to any other distro, too.

Bad news: The development of FTP-Proxy stopped quite a while ago. Anyway, you can [download the sources](http://ftp.suse.com/pub/projects/proxy-suite/src/) and compile it yourself.

Comment: And it is still included in [Debian packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=ftp-proxy).

Answer (score 2):

No, ftp doesn't have an equivalent of the HTTP/1.1 Host header so each FTP service has to have its own IP.

Comment: As of [RFC 7151](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7151), this is no longer true.  FTP now has an official `HOST` command, which provides functionality equivalent to HTTP 1.1's `Host` request header.